# Pythonanywhere Moviepy

Tags: python, imagemagick, moviepy

What is problem?

I'm running on Pythonanywhere.com

> This error can be due to the fact that ImageMagick is not installed on
>   your computer, or (for Windows users) that you didn't specify the path
>   to the ImageMagick binary in file conf.py, or.that the path you
>   specified is incorrect

```
[MoviePy] This command returned an error !Traceback (most recent call last):,

  File "deneme.py", line 6, in <module>

    txt_clip = TextClip("My Holidays 2013",fontsize=70,color='white')

  File "/home/pirali/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 1145, in __init__

    raise IOError(error)

IOError: MoviePy Error: creation of None failed because of the following error:

Youtube Foto Galeri: not authorized `@/tmp/tmpxjn5vu.txt' @ error/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/2959.
Youtube Foto Galeri: no images defined `PNG32:/tmp/tmp3lNxp8.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3044...

This error can be due to the fact that ImageMagick is not installed on your computer, or (for Windows users) that you didn't specify the path to the ImageMagick binary in file conf.py, or.that the path you specified is incorrect
```

Comment: "_This error can be due to the fact that ImageMagick is not installed on your computer, or (for Windows users) that you didn't specify the path to the ImageMagick binary in file conf.py, or.that the path you specified is incorrect_". Can you rule out all possible errors concerning this?

Comment: That error message gives you a _pile_ of possible reasons.    You've got a `None` showing up where it probably shouldn't, an authorization error, a complete lack of images (probably related to the authorization error), _and_ the ImageMagick suggestion Matthias quoted.  Surely you've investigated all these before asking here...  What were the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PythonAnywhere admin here.  For anyone else that might come across the problem, it was due to the ImageMagick security vulnerability that was discovered a few weeks ago:

https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=29588

Certain features in imagemagick are therefore disabled, pending security patches.